# Ajax sends null parameter to controller action

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to submit page inputs by Ajax in Asp.Net MVC.

JQuery Ajax json data is not null (checked in Console.log()), but it passes the json string null to controller action. Controller action aspects an object as string:

Class:

```
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public string ProductName { get; set; }
 public int CategoryID { get; set; }
 public int BrandID { get; set; }
 public int Price1 { get; set; }
 public string Exchange { get; set; }
 public bool State { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(string data)
    {
         //string data comes null here
    }
```

JQuery:

```
   var xy ={
             "data": { 
                 CategoryID: categoryID,
                 BrandID: brandID,
                 ProductName: productName,
                 Price1: price1,
                 ExchangeName: exchangeName,
                 State: state
             }
         };
         console.log(JSON.stringify(xy))

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Products/AddProduct/",
            type: 'POST',
             data: JSON.stringify(xy),          
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",         
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText)

            }
        });
```

output of console.log(JSON.stringify(xy)):

```
 {"data":{"CategoryID":"63","BrandID":"1","ProductName":"pname","Price1":"199","State":"1"}}
```

I checked lots of answers but couldn't figure out my issue. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(xy));`?

Comment: what parameters are present in `AddProduct` method? `data` or `CategoryID`, etc.?

Comment: I updated my question. AddProduct aspects class parameters as string json data from ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the name of the key you're sending the data in. Try this:

```
data: { data: JSON.stringify(xy.data) },
```

I'd also suggest that manually stringifying the data is needless additional work for you. It would make more sense to create a Model in your C# code and then let the ModelBinder work for you:

```js
data: xy.data,
```

```csharp
// model definition:
public class Product {
  public int CategoryID { get; set; }
  public int BrandID { get; set; }
  public string ProductName { get; set; }
  public decimal Price1 { get; set; }
  public string ExchangeName { get; set; }
  public string State { get; set; }
}

// in your controller:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(Product product)
{
  // work with the hydrated Product class here...
}
```

Comment: In your answer I am receiving "invalid json primitive: data " Interval Error 500

Answer (score 2):

in the action you need to declare all the params :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(int CategoryID, int BrandID, string ProductName, double Price1, string ExchangeName, int State)
{
}
```

and pass data like this :

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Products/AddProduct/",
            type: 'POST',
             data: {CategoryID: categoryID,
                 BrandID: brandID,
                 ProductName: productName,
                 Price1: price1,
                 ExchangeName: exchangeName,
                 State: state},          
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",         
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText)

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data: new{data = JSON.stringify(xy)}
```

pass your data like this way